# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error on `const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);`
It's declared as true from the get go so I can't understand how it's ever undefined

```
export default async function GetProducts() {
      const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
      const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
        useEffect(() => {
          if (isLoading) {
            let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products'  
            const res = axios.get(url);
            let data = res.json()
      }});
      if (isLoading) {
        return GetLoadingScreen()

  } else {
    return RenderProducts(products)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where are you importing the useState from?

Comment: import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

Comment: What bundler are you using? What is its configuration? That's a very strange error to be getting. (I know from the error you're using a bundler; with native ESM, you won't get that error.)

Comment: I don't know what a bundler is so I probably don't have one. The strange error is likely an effect of me not being able to write js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider not marking the React component function as async and marking the function created for `useEffect` as async instead.

```
export default function GetProducts() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    useEffect(async () => {
      if (isLoading) {
        let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products'  
        const res = await axios.get(url);
        let data = res.json()
  }});
  if (isLoading) {
    return GetLoadingScreen()
 } else {
    return RenderProducts(products)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting TypeError: res.json is not a function by doing this. Any suggestion? Getting it here, let data = res.json()

Comment: Figured it out, res.data is already json