# I want to resolve " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') " on TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm making typescript-react app.

I want to send HTTP Request with Axios and return response body.
but an error occurs in useState like below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at useState (react.development.js:1620:21)
```

I want to resolve this error. I spend few days with this.

My code is here. How can I Solve this?

```
const NOTICE_POSTS = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState<Data[]>([]); // error on this line

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  // const [error, setError] = useState<Error>();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getPosts() {
      try {
        const response: AxiosResponse<any> = await axios.get(
          "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
        );
        console.log("result.data: ", response.data.data);
        console.log("result: ", response.data);
        setData(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (e: any) {
        // setError(e);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
    getPosts();
  }, [data]);

  return [data, loading] as [Data[], boolean];
};
```

```
export interface Data {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}
```

Comment: did you tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/71904287/14994239 ?

Comment: I don't get your mentioned type error in my [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-kilby-k7jzbk?file=/src/App.tsx). Maybe adding null to your useState `useState<Data[]|null>([])` could help but not sure why I'm not getting the error.

Comment: I tried that. but error still occurs. I think error occurs outside of that code...

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this issue.

`NOTICE_POSTS()` is called outside.

```
const [datas, loading, error]: [Data[], Boolean, Error] = NOTICE_POSTS();
```

and these return values were declared global.

So, I moved those variables.
I think this issue caused by this reason.
That Function called before JS DOM Tree created...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).